# How to store a cache of Cache<String, byte[]> in Apache Ignite?

Tags: java, ignite

I would like to have a cache like this: `Cache<String, byte[]>`

Very simple use case here - store bytes associated with a string cache key. Not based on a Pojo. Just a plain byte array stored as the value.

What is the Apache Ignite way to do this? I found many articles online that all refer to Pojos and the Binarylizable interface. But my use case is more simple than that. No Pojos involved. I have bytes, and want them associated with a key. And when I fetch them, I want bytes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IgniteCache<String, byte[]> = ignite.createCache("cacheName");`

It's as easy as that.

Comment: Ah ok. yes it indeed is that simple. The reason why I was confused here was that if you have a Pojo with binary in it, that is a whole different story. That requires the whole `Binarylizable` thing.

Comment: By default it does not need `Binarylizable`. It may only be needed for speed boost and/or evolvability, but `new Object { byte[] field; }` will also be put and get back without any issues.

Comment: I'll have to figure out what I did wrong there then some other day. I have some legacy code doing stupid things. Like classes extending hashmap, etc. And ignite complained and demanded Binarylizable interface even though my class was Serializable

Comment: So basically what I did to work around the problem (I am in time crunch) is convert the pojo to bytes using `SerializableUtils` and write the bytes.